# How do I make a dropdown box clickable more than once?

Tags: jquery

I am just learning jquery and I am confused about how to make my information appear and reappear more than one time?

http://jsfiddle.net/U2h6e/

```
$(".drop").hide();
$(".experience").click(function(){
  $(".drop").show()
$(".experience").click(function(){
$(".drop").hide()
});
});
```

Comment: You can't nest click event handler like that. That keeps adding new ones every single time you click :)

Comment: After the first click you bind a function to the class that causes it to hide; both actions trigger (in order) and the object stays hidden. You may want to look at jquery toggle http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
$(".experience").click(function(){
    $(".drop").toggle();
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to trigger event, you can just use [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) of jQuery

And to show/hide use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) instead manually using `.show()`, `.hide()`

```
$(".experience").click(function(){
    $(".drop").toggle();
}

$(".experience").trigger("click");
```